# Creating a new Orchard site

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

I am currently configuring a new Orchard site.  I'd like to point the connectionstring to our development SQL database, but there is no option to do this.  Well, I say that, but I don't have an Orchard database in the first place to populate on the development server.  How do I create the Orchard database in the first place so that the developers can point to that instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have managed to figure this out.  I had to create an empty database and assign a user to that database.  Then, using the Orchard Setup, I was able to point the connection string to the new development database and this created all of the necessary tables.

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to use local file database SQL CE. It works perfectly fine for Orchard.
Later, if/when you will want to actually use SQL Server, you can migrate SQL CE contents in few clicks using WebMatrix:

1. Open your site in WebMatrix
2. Click Databases
3. Select your Orchard.sdf database
4. Click Migrate
5. Fill the address-login-password form, click Ok.

WebMatrix will not just copy database to SQL Server, but will also change your App_Data/Sites/Default/Settings.txt: it will change DataProvider and DataConnectionString lines.